# Phalcon CLI - setting dependency injection object correctly

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

I seem to be having trouble using Phalcon correctly in a CLI environment. I want to have a simple script that I can use to test some functions with quickly. I have created a dependency injector object like so:

```
class MainTask extends \Phalcon\CLI\Task {
     function validate($req, $index) {
         if ($req->hasPost($index)) {
             $val = ($req->getPost($index, 'trim'));
          }
          .....
 }

$di = new Phalcon\DI();
$di->set('data', function(){
    return "data";
});
$task = new MainTask();
$task->setDI($di);

$request = new Request();
$_POST['age'] = 10;
$ret = $task->validate($request, 'age');
```

But when I run it via "php test.php", I get the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Http\Request\Exception' with message 'A    dependency injection object is required to access the 'filter' service' in test.php:<line with trim in it>
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong here. I read the docs and it seems like this is the simplest way to achieve what I'm after. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create cli.php file (cli bootstrap) like described [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html#creating-a-bootstrap). Then you should create your tasks classes like described [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html#tasks). And then you can run it:

```
php cli.php task_name action_name
```